# Using SharedPreferences...did I do this right?

Tags: android, database, menu, onclick, http-post

I have a submenu that contains 3 choices for the user. Each option when chosen calls one of the 3 functions below:

```
    void viewLast5Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 4;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* Put PHP file link here */");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

void viewLast10Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 9;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* Put PHP file link here */");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

void viewLast20Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 19;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* Put PHP file link here */");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}
```

Each function creates a shared preference called lastpacketsPHP and puts a different URL into the preference. When assignInfoToHistoryTextView is called it calls another function located in a different class file. The class is shown below:

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Shc_BalloonSat_Activity extends Activity
{
int historyCountFromUser;
httpAPI api = new httpAPI(this);
kmlAPI kml = new kmlAPI(this);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#####");
DecimalFormat decimalf = new DecimalFormat("##.######");
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor prefEditor;
String lastpacketsPHP;

// User to determine how many packet the user would like to see.
int userDefinedCount = 4;

/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @param view */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String returned = null;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/get_last_5_BS_packets.php");

    try
    {
        returned = api.getData();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.info);
    infoTV.setText(returned);
    assignInfoToInfoTextView();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
    submenu.add(0, 5, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 5 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, 10, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 10 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, 20, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 20 Packets");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, submenu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.viewKML:
            viewKML();
            return true;
        case 5:
            viewLast5Packets();
            return true;
        case 10:
            viewLast10Packets();
            return true;
        case 20:
            viewLast5Packets();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void assignInfoToInfoTextView()
{
    TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.info); 

    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(api.result);
        for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
        {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(count);

            double altitudeData = json_data.getDouble("altitude");
            String infoText = "Last Known Altitude: " + df.format(altitudeData) + "\n";

            Double speedData = json_data.optDouble("speed");

            if (speedData.isNaN())
            {
                speedData = 0.00;
            }

            infoText += "Last Known Speed: " + df.format(speedData) + "\n";

            double recentLatitudeData = json_data.getDouble("latitude");
            infoText += "Last Known Latitude: " + df.format(recentLatitudeData) + "\n";

            double recentLongitudeData = json_data.getDouble("longitude");
            infoText += "Last Known Longtitude: " + df.format(recentLongitudeData) + "\n";

            infoTV.setText(infoText);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("<tag>", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error in (Last Known) method!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void assignInfoToHistoryTextView()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(api.result);

        for (int count = 1; count <= userDefinedCount; count++)
        {
            TextView historyTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.history);
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(count);

            double altitudeData = json_data.getDouble("altitude");
            String historyText = "Altitude: " + decimalf.format(altitudeData) + "\n";

            Double speedData = json_data.optDouble("speed");

            if (speedData.isNaN())
            {
                speedData = 0.00;
            }

            historyText += "Speed: " + df.format(speedData) + "\n";

            double latitudeData = json_data.getDouble("latitude");
            historyText += "Latitude: " + df.format(latitudeData) + "\n";

            double longitudeData = json_data.getDouble("longitude");
            historyText += "Longtitude: " + df.format(longitudeData) + "\n\n";

            historyTV.append(historyText);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data: " + e.toString());
    }

}

void viewLast5Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 4;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/get_last_5_BS_packets.php");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

void viewLast10Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 9;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/get_last_10_BS_packets.php");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

void viewLast20Packets()
{
    userDefinedCount = 19;
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/get_last_20_BS_packets.php");
    prefEditor.commit();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
}

public void viewKML()
{
    kml.openKML();
}
}
```

In the httpPost I'm trying to set it so that it will call whichever PHP file was chosen depending on what option was chosen by the user. I'm doing this by inserting get the value of the preference and putting that in the httpPost. When I run the app in the emulator it crashes immediately and it didn't happen until I put the preference code in the httpPost so I know my syntax is wrong I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I get these errors at runtime with the code above:

```
02-02 13:42:14.973: E/AndroidRuntime(230): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-02 13:42:15.213: D/dalvikvm(230): GC freed 3178 objects / 319424 bytes in 131ms
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.java:588)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:59)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.os.Looper.myLooper(Looper.java:137)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:119)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:673)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:21)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:24)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.httpAPI.<init>(httpAPI.java:20)
02-02 13:42:15.283: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.<init>(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.

02-02 13:42:15.373: I/dalvikvm(230): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-02 13:42:15.373: E/dalvikvm(230): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class httpAPI
{
    Shc_BalloonSat_Activity shc;

    ...

        httppost = new HttpPost(shc.pref.getString(shc.lastpacketsPHP,
                                shc.lastpacketsPHP.toString()));
```

Initially, the trouble was that shc was being used without being initialized.  Following up with the question, since the `HttpPost` object needs a `SharedPreferences` instance (which is accessible via a context), I'd suggest adding a constructor to the `httpAPI` class.  For example:

```
public class httpAPI {

    Shc_BalloonSat_Activity shc;
    HttpPost httppost;

    ...

    public httpAPI(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity aContext) {
        shc = aContext;
    }

    ...

    public String getData() throws Exception {
        ...
        httppost = new HttpPost(shc.pref.getString(shc.lastpacketsPHP, shc.lastpacketsPHP.toString());
```

Comment: I added a constructor to shc and it still crashes immediately when it loads.

Comment: Can you update your example with the code you use to set shc?

Comment: You can't really just call an Activity's constructor like that.  You should have a constructor for the `httpAPI` class that accepts a `Shc_BalloonSat_Activity` as a parameter.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I updated my original question with some more information for you.

Comment: Try deferring the construction of httppost until after the Shc constructor is completed.  This may be restructuring your code - its stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: How do I do that when all of my initializations and constructors are before my functions?

Comment: Refactor, and initialize at the latest possible moment.

Comment: One of my friends was able to debug it. In my shc class I was calling the other class and in the other class I was calling the shc class. So it was looping that infinitely. Then I also had a Null pointer exception which my friend was able to figure out....Thanks for your help!